# Connection failure in oracle developer tool

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I downloaded an oracle sql-developer tool and configured it correctly. Then I used a default username and password hr and other one is system. Yet, it is showing an error like the one below. I am trying to use it locally but it does not seem to be connected??

I am using an `Ubuntu 12.10 OS` and `oracle 4.0`.

```
Error::Status-Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter
could not establish the connection.
```

Comment: Make sure that the hostname, port and SID/SErvicename you have provided are correct and as per the local Oracle installation, which you're trying to connect to.

Comment: hostname:localhost port:1521 SID:xe which i had provide?

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1034452?tstart=0

Comment: `sqlplus user/pass@db` works? also do `lsnrctl` and check status.

Comment: no its showing a same error only::

Comment: Looks like you only installed sqldeveloper, and no Oracle database. sqldeveloper is only a developer tool. To use Oracle, you need to download and install the database software (About 2GB download. 11g or 12c should work on Linux). Installing it can be a bit tricky, you can find how-to's on the net: http://www.makina-corpus.org/blog/howto-install-oracle-11g-ubuntu-linux-1204-precise-pangolin-64bits

Comment: yes i download sqldeveloper not Oracle database so where to download       Oracle database??

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Oracle Database first. Download it at oracle.com (you need to register for a developer account - it's free): http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html

Installation of 12c on Ubuntu is a bit complicated. Follow this tutorial, for example: http://gemsofprogramming.wordpress.com/2013/09/19/installing-oracle-12c-on-ubuntu-12-04-64-bit-a-hard-journey-but-its-worth-it/